# Inconsistent display of font-face on devices when applying font-weight

Tags: ios, css, font-face

I have this issue with a font display on iDevices. When the `font-weight` is set to bold, the display is much wider and different. What could be the reason?

expected (from desktop pc):

[image: expected]

device (iphone 4S or iPad):

[image: device]

this is how I declare the font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ITCAvantGardeGothicBook';
    src: url('/assets/font/avantgarde-book-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/assets/font/avantgarde-book-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/assets/font/avantgarde-book-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/assets/font/avantgarde-book-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/assets/font/avantgarde-book-webfont.svg#ITCAvantGardeGothicBook') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desktop PC may have the `ITCAvantGardeGothicBook` **bold** font installed locally as a separate ttf file - so it renders bold as expected. However your webpage only provides a single reference to a font-face at the normal font-weight... so the browser must mock up a faux bold when viewed on the iPhone. The faux bold will never look as good as a true bold font.

If you want your bold font to look perfect, include a separate bold font-face with a link to an actual bold font.

Read this post for more information on why this is important:
http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-use-font-face-avoid-faux-italic-and-bold-browser-styles

Comment: That's interesting. The issue now is that the `bold` font that I have is also different to the _faux_ bold version of `book`. In fact, I have as ttf book, bold, demi and medium. I don't know what to do if the bold version I prefer is not the official `bold` ttf.

Comment: You should be able to work it out with the right @font-face declarations. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but linking up a real bold font should keep the page from reverting to the ugly faux bold.